# for making the sample passbook app , in fetching in .pkpass file NSData is nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, passbook

```
NSString *filePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"freehugcoupon.pkpass"];
NSLog(@"Filepath = [%@]",filePath);
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

NSError *error;
if (data != nil) {
    PKPass *pass = [[PKPass alloc] initWithData:data error:&error];
    NSLog(@"Error = [%@]",[error localizedDescription]);

    if([passLib containsPass:pass]) {

        UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Pass Exists" message:@"The pass you are trying to add to Passbook is already present." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
        [alertView release];

    } else {

        PKAddPassesViewController *vc = [[PKAddPassesViewController alloc] initWithPass:pass];
        vc.delegate = self;
        [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
        [vc release];
        [pass release];
    }
}
```

---

While fetching for NSData from .pkpass file from the local path  i am getting the NSData object is nil ...

can anyone help me 
thanks in advance.

Comment: check nsdata for nslog(@"%@" , nsData);

Answer (score 1):

If your `NSData` object is `nil` it means your `dataWithContentsOfFile:` call didn't work. Check that your `filePath` is valid - if it isn't, that's your problem.